# Splitting a mixed string/number argument list of a Lua function call in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt, parsing, qt4.8

I want to parse the argument list of a Lua function call in C++ using Qt (4.8) in order to avoid a dependency to the Lua interpreter. The comma-separated argument list can be assumed to consist only of string literals and numbers. Eventually the result should be available as a `QStringList`. The tricky part there is to cope with commas that are part of string arguments as well with the fact that string arguments may use single or double quotes. Until I get to a solution (using regular expressions) myself, somebody might already have dealt with that or a similar problem.

**Example:**

The argument list string

```
"Foo", "not 'bar'", 'a, b ,c', 42, 1e-8
```

should be transformed to a string list containing the items

`Foo`, `not 'bar'`, `a, b, c`, `42` and `1e-8`

(omitting the quotes per item to avoid confusion)

Comment: Have you look at [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/tokenizer/) ?

Comment: @Jarod42: No need for boost. QString::split returns QStringList.

Comment: @Jarod42: I would prefer to solely use the means provided by Qt which should already be sufficient to solve the problem. On the other hand, boost::tokenizer would treat commas inside string literals also as separators just as QString::split does, right?

Comment: Its handle quote and escape: look at [Escaped List Separator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/tokenizer/escaped_list_separator.htm)

Comment: Yes, it looks like this is the functionality I am looking for. If I don't get to a pure Qt solution I will consider this.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with all the possibilities of your arguments, but the examples you mentioned get correctly matched with this: `(?<=")[\w',-]*?(?=")|(?<=^'|\s').*(?='(?:,|$))|[\w-]+`, as seen here: https://regex101.com/r/rX7fX7/3

The idea is that you write the "difficult" situations in alternations, preferably to the left, while the less difficult solutions to the right. This way, the engine will first check if a problem situation is present before trying to match whole words.

The current regex doesn't work correctly if quotes/doublequotes appear in middle of the arguments, but your examples didn't have such situations.

Comment: This is quite promising, unfortunately it does not work for me as Qt 4.8 regular expressions do not support lookbehinds, and upgrading to Qt 5 is currently not an option for me. I edited the question regarding the "quotes inside strings" example and added a Qt 4.8 tag.

Comment: Well, you can always replace lookbehinds with non-capturing groups and capturing the matches, but that would require matching capturegroup results into an array. If you're interested in such a solution, i can write it.